# Populate TreeView from list of paths with values

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have some data in a text file which is formatted like this:

```
A.B.C=12
A.B.D=13
A.C.D=14
```

and need to put it into a treeview control so that it looks like this:

[image]

The tag values of the ends should equal what they did in the text, ie. C = 12.

Most of what I've tried has been centered around using a foreach loop on each line, and then splitting the string on the '.'s and '=' and looping through those, but I have not been able to get it to work at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: The string split ('.') is a good start. Post the code that you have and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach to your question. Comments are in code.
Works with your sample data but I cannot guarantee it will work in some other cases :)

Main method is `PopulateTreeView()` so call it from, in example, form's `Load` event. Also, there is helper method `FindNode` which is used to search through first level of nodes to find if node with supplied text exists.

If you have additional questions, feel free to ask.

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
{
    //read from file
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\tree.txt");
    //go through all the lines
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        //split by dot to get nodes names
        var nodeNames = line.Split('.');
        //TreeNode to remember node level
        TreeNode lastNode = null;

        //iterate through all node names
        foreach (string nodeName in nodeNames)
        {
            //values for name and tag (tag is empty string by default)
            string name = nodeName;
            string tagValue = string.Empty;
            //if node is in format "name=value", change default values of name and tag value. If not, 
            if (nodeName.Contains("="))
            {
                name = nodeName.Split('=')[0];
                tagValue = nodeName.Split('=')[1];
            }

            //var used for finding existing node
            TreeNode existingNode = null;
            //new node to add to tree
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(name);
            newNode.Tag = tagValue;
            //collection of subnodes to search for node name (to check if node exists)
            //in first pass, that collection is collection of treeView's nodes (first level)
            TreeNodeCollection nodesCollection = treeView1.Nodes;

            //with first pass, this will be null, but in every other, this will hold last added node.
            if (lastNode != null)
            {
                nodesCollection = lastNode.Nodes;
            }

            //look into collection if node is already there (method checks only first level of node collection)
            existingNode = FindNode(nodesCollection, name);
            //node is found? In that case, skip it but mark it as last "added"
            if (existingNode != null)
            {
                lastNode = existingNode;
                continue;
            }
            else //not found so add it to collection and mark node as last added.
            {
                nodesCollection.Add(newNode);
                lastNode = newNode;
            }
        }
    }

    treeView1.ExpandAll();
}

private TreeNode FindNode(TreeNodeCollection nodeCollectionToSearch, string nodeText)
{
    var nodesToSearch = nodeCollectionToSearch.Cast<TreeNode>();
    var foundNode = nodesToSearch.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Text == nodeText);
    return foundNode;
}
```