# Way to build tree from list of path strings

Tags: c#

I have the following list of `ContentData` objects (see below the class structure):

```
Name = "Path1\\Path2\\Path3\\File0", Size = 110
Name = "Path1\\Path2\\Path4\\File1", Size = 112
Name = "Path1\\Path2\\Path4\\File2", Size = 22222
Name = "Path1\\Path5\\File3", Size = 2312313
Name = "Path6", Size = 0
```

I want to build a tree which should look like:

```
Path1
    -> Path2
        -> Path3
            -> File0
        -> Path4
            -> File1
            -> File2
    -> Path5
        -> File3
Path6
```

I tried:

```
public static IEnumerable<TreeDataModel> GetTree(this IEnumerable<ContentData> dataList, Func<ContentData, string> nameSelector, string root = null)
{
  var enumerable = root != null ? dataList.Where(data => nameSelector(data).Equals(root)) : dataList;
  foreach (var data in enumerable)
  {
    var split = data.Name.Split('\\');

    if (split.Length > 1)
    {
      yield return new TreeDataModel(split[0], "", dataList.GetTree(nameSelector, string.Join("\\", split.Skip(1))));
    }
    else
    {
      yield return new TreeDataModel(split[0], "", null);
    }
  }
}
```

and `ContentData` contains

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public long Size { get; set; }
```

and `TreeDataModel`

```
public sealed class TreeDataModel
{
    public TreeDataModel(string title, string path, IEnumerable<TreeDataModel> children)
    {
      Title = title;
      Path = path;
      Children = children;
    }

    public string Title { get; }

    public string Path { get; }

    public IEnumerable<TreeDataModel> Children { get; }
}
```

I'm stucked at extension and I don't know how to achieve the results.

Means that the results I got now is that appears multiple times same first part before \

Comment: "I'm stucked at extension" - What do you mean by "stucked"? What exactly is the problem you are facing? As it stands, the question is way too vague.

Comment: You can find some similar discussion  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330937/populate-treeview-from-list-of-paths-with-values replace split in solution from . to  /

Comment: @phuzi  I edited ... I’m stuck means I have no idea what is the problem with that extension to achieve mentioned desire

Comment: @Oleg thanks I will take a look over the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code like below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication54
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<ContentData> data = new List<ContentData>() {
                new ContentData("Path1\\Path2\\Path3\\File0", 110),
                new ContentData("Path1\\Path2\\Path4\\File1", 112),
                new ContentData("Path1\\Path2\\Path4\\File2", 22222),
                new ContentData("Path1\\Path5\\File3", 2312313),
                new ContentData("Path6", 0)
            };

            CreateTreeRecursive(data, null, 0);
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        public void CreateTreeRecursive(List<ContentData> data, TreeNode node, int index)
        {
            var groupData = data.Where(x => x.splitName.Length > index).GroupBy(x => x.splitName[index]).ToList();
            foreach (var group in groupData)
            {
                TreeNode newNode  = new TreeNode(group.Key);
                if (node == null)
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                }
                else
                {
                    node.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                }
                CreateTreeRecursive(group.ToList(), newNode, index + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    public class ContentData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string[] splitName { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }

        public ContentData(string name, int size)
        {
            Name = name;
            Size = size;
            splitName = name.Split(new char[] {'\\'}).ToArray();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I  changed following to simplify : TreeNode newNode  = new TreeNode(group.Key);

Comment: I don't use treeview from WPF ... I use custom object (and want display it on Razor view page, for example)

Comment: Still the algorithm should work.  Just need to convert code to WPF.